# Ckeditor 4 does not encode accented chars

Tags: javascript, c#, ckeditor

I am using the ck editor (version 4) and users enter greek text. Most characters are converted into html entities but the accented characters seem to be ignored.

On my page and within my database the text is stored an can be displayed but when I create an email with the entered text the characters are not shown correctly.

Is there a config setting that I can use so that all greek characters are converted? Or do I have to try and change these characters manually?

Comment: Did you try setting the [`config.entities_greek`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_greek) option to `true`?

Comment: Yes, this flag is set to true. Most of the greek characters are encoded. The accented ones just seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an encoding issue rather than converting the characters into entities. Presumably the text is being stored as UTF-8 in the database, and the webs pages are also in the same encoding, so the characters get displayed correctly.

When it comes to the email, I suspect that it's being encoded in another encoding like ASCII or ISO-8859-1 (Latin characters only) so the Greek text will appear as a mix of letters and punctuation rather than as it should look.

You don't mention what you're using to send the email, but I'd probably look there first to see if there's a way of setting the character encoding to the same encoding as the data is stored in the database.

Comment: I am sending an HTML Mail via smtp. When I open the Mail in my Outlook and check the metatags the encoding is set to UTF-8. 

I was thinking that I was an converting problem because most of the greek characters are converted into html Tags. Just the accented greek characters are not converted. 

`&sigma;&chi;&epsilon;&tau;&iota;&kappa;ά &mu;&epsilon;`